# rotation animation for specific duration when clicked via pure css

Tags: css

i want rotation animation on a image present in a div via pure CSS3 animation triggered when the image is clicked.
the animation shuld be for specific duration.

Comment: Please push your code for better understanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one solution I can think of for triggering the rotation on click would be to use the checkbox hack and [**keyframe animations**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/@keyframes) - see [**DEMO**](http://dabblet.com/gist/3697196)

HTML used:

```
<div class='img-container'>
    <input type='checkbox' name='t' id='t'><label for='t'></label>
    <img src='http://imgsrc.hubblesite.org/hu/db/images/hs-1998-14-i-web.jpg'>
</div>
```

Relevant CSS:

```
.img-container {
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
    height: 295px;
}
.img-container input[type=checkbox] { display: none; }
.img-container input[type=checkbox] + label, .img-container img {
    position: absolute;
    min-width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.img-container input[type=checkbox] + label {
    z-index: 2;
}
.img-container img { z-index: 1; }
.img-container input[type=checkbox] ~ img { animation: rev-rotate-img 1s; }
.img-container input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ img { animation: rotate-img 1s; }

@keyframes rotate-img { to { transform: rotate(360deg); } }
@keyframes rev-rotate-img { to { transform: rotate(-360deg); } }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi now used to this it's helpfull for you

***[Link one](http://www.the-art-of-web.com/css/css-animation/)***

***[Link two](http://www.pxleyes.com/blog/2010/05/animating-with-pure-css-and-webkit/)***

***[Link Three](http://demo.marcofolio.net/3d_animation_css3/)***

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by combining `@keyframes` with CSS3 `animation` command. A simple method should look like this:

```
-webkit-animation:
    roll-over-rotate 400ms .1s 1 ease-in-out normal forwards,
    roll-over-color 1000ms ease-out;
-moz-animation:
    roll-over-rotate 400ms .1s 1 ease-in-out normal forwards,
    roll-over-color 1000ms ease-out;

@-webkit-keyframes roll-over-rotate {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes roll-over-rotate {
  from {
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
  }
}
```

First define the webkit animation then make reference to the animation function where you define the desired CSS3 specific effect.

For a live example you should check the css part of this experiment: http://www.hellopixel.net/experiments/javascript/worley-noise/worley.html